# Does IE/Edge animate calc() CSS specs appropriately?

Tags: css, css-animations, microsoft-edge

**Demonstration Link:** https://codepen.io/jodriscoll/pen/wRpQOw

I'm working on a "sidewards blind-like" animation behavior, where when a user hovers over an object (anchor), it expands the object (anchor) in width and creates a perception of showing more of the objects contain within (think of a clipping mask of sorts).

Initially the video/image object is styled in a way to prevent it from moving 1:1 with the "clipping mask" (anchor wrapping the video/image). Meaning, it is already offset to the position it should be when the user hovers over the anchor.

Both the image and the video are initially styled to fill the entirety of the anchor AND the gutter gaps; this helps when animating to create the perception that we're just showing more of the photo, no actually resizing it and causing it to move on screen (sorry, that might be confusing...):

```
left: -24px;              // the width of each gutter gap
width: calc(100% + 48px); // fill the parent + fill the gutter gaps
```

When the user hovers over the anchor, the child elements change their CSS specs to:

```
left: 0;     // stay flush with the anchor object
width: 100%; // fill the parent, which now includes the gutter gap(s)
```

Everything appears to work correctly when viewing the animation behaviors on **Chrome / Safari / Firefox**:

- http://svg-gmmb-cis.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/debugging_animations.mp4

Unfortunately, there is a slight hiccup on **IE11/Edge**:

- http://svg-gmmb-cis.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IE_animation_bug.mp4

**Questions and hopeful helpful insight towards reaching an answer:**

- After viewing the animation glitch, does IE11/Edge have issues with animating CSS measures using `calc()`?
- Do I need to create a CSS animation with keyframes to remedy this hiccup in IE11/Edge?
- Am I approaching this wrong and should be animating different properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with margin and avoid the use of `calc`.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 0 24px;
  height:100px;
}
.box {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  transition:.5s all;
}
.box:hover {
  margin:0 -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 0 24px;
  height:100px;
}
.box {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  transition:.5s all;
}
.box:hover {
  margin:0 -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm aware of this approach, unfortunately, the markup for my application is a bit more complex ( and needs to be ). If you're able to isolate the CSS animation issue in the codepen example, I'm happy to rethink my approach utilizing that markup. Thanks!

Comment: Can you inform us, Which version of MS Edge you are using currently? I run your code in Chrome and Edge but did not find any difference in output. Your testing video also don't show that testing was done in the Edge. So can you please add a test with Edge app window? it can help to understand the issue in better way.